# How do I play 30 seconds of an avplayeritem?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I can play the whole entire song, but I want to only play 30 seconds of it. How would I do that?

```
if let url: String = "hiddingthelink"{

        let urlplayer = NSURL(string: url)
        let playeritem = AVPlayerItem(URL:(urlplayer)!)
        player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playeritem)
        self.player.volume = 1.0
        self.player.rate = 1.0
        self.player.play()
    }
```

Comment: try `  player.performSelector(Selector("pause"), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 30)`

Comment: Use KVO. Observe `player.currentTime()` . When it reaches 30 seconds, `player.pause()`